# OpenCV - face_cascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier(classifier)

Tags: node.js, opencv

I got this error message when execute node script

```
/Users/ZERO/node_modules/opencv/lib/opencv.js:22
    face_cascade = new cv.CascadeClassifier(classifier);
                   ^

TypeError: Error loading file
    at TypeError (native)
    at Matrix.detectObject (/Users/ZERO/node_modules/opencv/lib/opencv.js:22:20)
    at /Users/ZERO/RM1/index.js:14:8
    at /Users/ZERO/RM1/index.js:13:6
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ZERO/RM1/index.js:12:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

My script

```
var cv = require('opencv');

var color       = [0, 255, 0];
var thickness   = 2;
var cascadeFile = '/Users/ZERO/RM1/classifier/cascade.xml';

var inputFiles = [
  '/Users/ZERO/RM1/recognize/recognize_this_1.jpg', 
  '/Users/ZERO/RM1/recognize/recognize_this_2.jpg', 
  '/Users/ZERO/RM1/recognize/recognize_this_3.jpg',
  '/Users/ZERO/RM1/recognize/recognize_this_4.jpg', 
  '/Users/ZERO/RM1/recognize/recognize_this_5.jpg', 
  '/Users/ZERO/RM1/recognize/recognize_this_6.jpg'
];

inputFiles.forEach(function(fileName) {
  cv.readImage(fileName, function(err, im) {
    im.detectObject(cascadeFile, {neighbors: 2, scale: 2}, function(err, objects) {
      console.log(objects);
      for(var k = 0; k < objects.length; k++) {
        var object = objects[k];
        im.rectangle(
          [object.x, object.y],
          [object.x + object.width, object.y + object.height],
          color,
          2
        );
      }
      im.save(fileName.replace(/\.jpg/, 'processed.jpg'));
    });
  });
});
```